# Convert Java Date to UTC String

Tags: java, datetime, string-formatting, utc

The [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) `toString()` method displays the date in the local time zone.

There are several common scenarios where we want the data to be printed in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), including logs, data export and communication with external programs.

- What's the best way to create a String representation of `java.util.Date` in UTC?
- How to replace the j.u.Date’s `toString()` format, which isn't sortable (thanks, @JonSkeet!) with a better format?

#### Addendum

I think that the standard way of printing the date in a custom format and time zone is quite tedious:

```java
final Date date = new Date();
final String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
sdf.setTimeZone(utc);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

I was looking for a one-liner like:

```java
System.out.println(prettyPrint(date, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz", "UTC"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal String format"?

Comment: The same format in which Java.Util.Date is printed, "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", e.g. "Mon Jul 02 16:01:57 IDT 2012".

Comment: Dear downvoters, please be informative.

Comment: That seems like a bad format to use for *all* the examples you gave. Why not use an extended ISO-8601 representation? (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS`) It's locale-independent, sortable, fixed-length, and easier to parse.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed. I used it only because it is the Java default, meaning that it is probably common in logs and other applications that  simply print a `Date` object.

Comment: The default is so poor that I would *hope* it's rarely used. It's not like it's *hard* to use `SimpleDateFormat` to do better.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed, updating accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've changed to code to support ISO format, Legacy format, and string configuration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following the useful comments, I've completely rebuilt the date formatter. Usage is supposed to:

- Be short (one liner)
- Represent disposable objects (time zone, format) as Strings
- Support useful, sortable ISO formats and the legacy format from the box

If you consider this code useful, I may publish the source and a JAR in github.

#### Usage

```java
// The problem - not UTC
Date.toString()                      
"Tue Jul 03 14:54:24 IDT 2012"

// ISO format, now
PrettyDate.now()        
"2012-07-03T11:54:24.256 UTC"

// ISO format, specific date
PrettyDate.toString(new Date())         
"2012-07-03T11:54:24.256 UTC"

// Legacy format, specific date
PrettyDate.toLegacyString(new Date())   
"Tue Jul 03 11:54:24 UTC 2012"

// ISO, specific date and time zone
PrettyDate.toString(moonLandingDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz", "CST") 
"1969-07-20 03:17:40 CDT"

// Specific format and date
PrettyDate.toString(moonLandingDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
"1969-07-20"

// ISO, specific date
PrettyDate.toString(moonLandingDate)
"1969-07-20T20:17:40.234 UTC"

// Legacy, specific date
PrettyDate.toLegacyString(moonLandingDate)
"Wed Jul 20 08:17:40 UTC 1969"
```

#### Code

*(This code is also the subject of [a question on Code Review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/java-date-formatter))*

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * Formats dates to sortable UTC strings in compliance with ISO-8601.
 * 
 * @author Adam Matan <adam@matan.name>
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294307/convert-java-date-to-utc-string/11294308
 */
public class PrettyDate {
    public static String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
    public static String LEGACY_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    private static final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat legacyFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(LEGACY_FORMAT);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat isoFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
    static {
        legacyFormatter.setTimeZone(utc);
        isoFormatter.setTimeZone(utc);
    }

    /**
     * Formats the current time in a sortable ISO-8601 UTC format.
     * 
     * @return Current time in ISO-8601 format, e.g. :
     *         "2012-07-03T07:59:09.206 UTC"
     */
    public static String now() {
        return PrettyDate.toString(new Date());
    }

    /**
     * Formats a given date in a sortable ISO-8601 UTC format.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * final Calendar moonLandingCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     * moonLandingCalendar.set(1969, 7, 20, 20, 18, 0);
     * final Date moonLandingDate = moonLandingCalendar.getTime();
     * System.out.println("UTCDate.toString moon:       " + PrettyDate.toString(moonLandingDate));
     * >>> UTCDate.toString moon:       1969-08-20T20:18:00.209 UTC
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param date
     *            Valid Date object.
     * @return The given date in ISO-8601 format.
     * 
     */

    public static String toString(final Date date) {
        return isoFormatter.format(date);
    }

    /**
     * Formats a given date in the standard Java Date.toString(), using UTC
     * instead of locale time zone.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * System.out.println(UTCDate.toLegacyString(new Date()));
     * >>> "Tue Jul 03 07:33:57 UTC 2012"
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @param date
     *            Valid Date object.
     * @return The given date in Legacy Date.toString() format, e.g.
     *         "Tue Jul 03 09:34:17 IDT 2012"
     */
    public static String toLegacyString(final Date date) {
        return legacyFormatter.format(date);
    }

    /**
     * Formats a date in any given format at UTC.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * <code>
     * final Calendar moonLandingCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     * moonLandingCalendar.set(1969, 7, 20, 20, 17, 40);
     * final Date moonLandingDate = moonLandingCalendar.getTime();
     * PrettyDate.toString(moonLandingDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
     * >>> "1969-08-20"
     * </code>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * @param date
     *            Valid Date object.
     * @param format
     *            String representation of the format, e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd"
     * @return The given date formatted in the given format.
     */
    public static String toString(final Date date, final String format) {
        return toString(date, format, "UTC");
    }

    /**
     * Formats a date at any given format String, at any given Timezone String.
     * 
     * 
     * @param date
     *            Valid Date object
     * @param format
     *            String representation of the format, e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
     * @param timezone
     *            String representation of the time zone, e.g. "CST"
     * @return The formatted date in the given time zone.
     */
    public static String toString(final Date date, final String format, final String timezone) {
        final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone);
        final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michael-O: That last edit on this post was way out of line, and should have been a comment instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus I do not even remember it. Still makes the answer wrong because the formatting simply isn't ISO 8601. Period.

Comment: @Michael-O: Then leave a comment about that fact and if it's true and of importance in context of the answer your comment will get upvotes so everybody sees it prominently.

Comment: It is indeed true that `CDT`, `UDT`, etc. are not ISO-8601 timezone specifiers, and that's useful to note. Editing exhortations to downvote into a answer is **not** useful.

Comment: Just to be clear, the answer *is wrong* to claim that datetime strings like `"2012-07-03T11:54:24.256 UTC"` are in "ISO format" and *should* be downvoted for that reason. That isn't changed by the fact that @Michael-O went about drawing attention to the error in an objectionable way. Michael, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303570/should-you-let-users-edit-other-peoples-answer-to-encourage-downvoting, by the way, if you haven't already.

Comment: @MarkAmery and yet no one did update the incorrect answer. I don't get the fuzz.

Comment: @Michael-O if you know the answer, why don't you post it?

Comment: `2015-07-17T00:00:00.000+02:00` and `2015-07-17T00:00:00.000Z` are valid ISO8601 format. The one in this post is not valid.

Comment: Anyway, to make the output of this code actually ISO 8601 compliant, set `ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX"`.

Comment: and the LEGACY_FORMAT should be "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", which is found in a comment in the source of Date.toString()

Answer (score 54):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> I was looking for a one-liner like:

Ask and ye shall receive. Convert from terrible legacy class `Date` to its modern replacement, `Instant`.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().toString()
```

> 2020-05-05T19:46:12.912Z

## java.time

In Java 8 and later we have the new [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built in ([Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). Inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310, and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

The best solution is to **sort your date-time objects rather than strings**. But if you must work in strings, read on.

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline, basically in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (see class doc for precise details). The [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) implementation uses the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) format by default. This format includes zero, three, six or nine digits digits as needed to display fraction of a second up to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) precision.

```
String output = Instant.now().toString(); // Example: '2015-12-03T10:15:30.120Z'
```

If you must interoperate with the old `Date` class, convert to/from java.time via new methods added to the old classes. Example: `Date::toInstant`.

```
myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().toString()
```

You may want to use an alternate formatter if you need a consistent number of digits in the fractional second or if you need no fractional second.

Another route if you want to truncate fractions of a second is to use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `Instant`, calling its [method to change the fraction to zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withNano-int-).

Note that we must specify a time zone for `ZonedDateTime` (thus the name). In our case that means UTC. The subclass of [`ZoneID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html), holds a convenient [constant for UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). If we omit the time zone, the JVM’s [current default time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) is implicitly applied.

```
String output = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).withNano( 0 ).toString();  // Example: 2015-08-27T19:28:58Z
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The Joda -Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

> I was looking for a one-liner

Easy if using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is the default formatting.

### Time Zone

In the code example below, note that I am specifying a time zone rather than depending on the default time zone. In this case, I'm specifying [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) per your question. The `Z` on the end, spoken as "Zulu", means no time zone offset from UTC.

### Example Code

```
// import org.joda.time.*;

String output = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Output…

```
2013-12-12T18:29:50.588Z
```

Comment: Down vote with no comment? The question asked for a one-liner outputting date-time in UTC, and I gave one.

Comment: One liner using Joda-Time for existing Date instance: `new DateTime(date).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString()`

Answer (score 8):

The following simplified code, based on [the accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11294308), worked for me:

```
public class GetSync {
    public static String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
    private static final TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat isoFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
    static {
        isoFormatter.setTimeZone(utc);
    }

    public static String now() {
        return isoFormatter.format(new Date()).toString();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Note that, as with the accepted answer, to actually get valid ISO 8601 compliant output you should use `ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX"`.

Comment: Update: The terrible classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time.Instant

Just use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) of `java.time`.

```
    System.out.println(Instant.now());
```

This just printed:

```
2018-01-27T09:35:23.179612Z
```

`Instant.toString` always gives UTC time.

The output is *usually* sortable, but there are unfortunate exceptions. `toString` gives you enough groups of three decimals to render the precision it holds. On the Java 9 on my Mac the precision of `Instant.now()` seems to be microseconds, but we should expect that in approximately one case out of a thousand it will hit a whole number of milliseconds and print only three decimals. Strings with unequal numbers of decimals will be sorted in the wrong order (unless you write a custom comparator to take this into account).

`Instant` is one of the classes in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, which I warmly recommend that you use instead of the outdated `Date` class. `java.time` is built into Java 8 and later and has also been backported to Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

If XStream is a dependency, try:

```
new com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.DateConverter().toString(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to use java.util.Date only, here is a small trick you can use:

String dateString = Long.toString(Date.UTC(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()));

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use java.text.SimpleDateFormat ?

```
Date someDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String s = df.format(someDate);
```

Or see:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Comment: Where is the conversion to UTC? The OP is already using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Update: The terrible classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.