# Saving date() in JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to save the current date (among other data) in a JSON file in LocalStorage.
So far I get to save the data, but JSON will save it in the ISO 8601 format:

```
[{"date":"2014-10-13T17:55:32.953Z"}]
```

It kinda makes it hard for me later when I want to call the data back and filter it and so on.
Is there some way to change the date() format (To DD-MM-YYYY, for instance) before parsing into the JSON file?

Here's my current code:

```
$scope.dateHeader = new Date(); 

$scope.recordlist = extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage();

$scope.addRecord = function () {
    $scope.recordlist.push({ date: $scope.dateHeader});

    jsonToRecordLocalStorage($scope.recordlist);
};

function extractRecordJSONFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("records")) || [

    ];
}
function jsonToRecordLocalStorage(recordlist) {
    var jsonRecordlist = angular.toJson(recordlist);

    if (jsonRecordlist != 'null') {
        localStorage.setItem("records", jsonRecordlist);
    } else {
        alert("Invalid JSON!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can trow in my direction!

Comment: What's so hard about using ISO 8601 in your code later? Keep it stored in that format and convert it when you need to display it in a view, not when you store it. Among other things, `YYYY-MM-DD` format will sort correctly without a special sort function, while `DD-MM-YYYY` will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Moment JS, I think it will solve your problem.

Info about momentJS can be found here :- http://momentjs.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$scope.dateHeader = $filter('date')(new Date(),'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take the date in a converted string such that its eazy for you to get while parsing ,many of the APIs are also using these techniques to save the current date/time.
Eg : you wanted to take your date/time like

```
month date year hr min sec
```

then you convert it to anytime stamp such that java provides conversion method from one time stamp to another.

eg `your date is 13-13-1992 and time is 7:48:78 then your date string will be 726909318`
also you can convert to any other time stamp you prefer.
[Visit This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294307/convert-java-date-to-utc-string)